# Pandas drop_duplicates -> Fatal Python error: deallocating None

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I have a code that checks an Excel sheet, and if it finds some changes, then takes a snapshot (Pandas Dataframe) of the whole sheet and saves it to a csv with a timestamp.
It has been running all day doing it's job correctly, but usually once or twice a day I got the error message below:

```
Fatal Python error: deallocating None

Current thread 0x000013d4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1655 in take_nd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1238 in take_nd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1235 in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1235 in reindex_indexer
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1350 in take
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3359 in _take
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2969 in _getitem_bool_array
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2918 in __getitem__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4637 in drop_duplicates
  File "C:\Python projects\RTD_recorder_1thrd_Pandas.py", line 79 in <module>
```

This is the code which causes the freeze:

```
final_result = pd.concat([final_result, difference]).drop_duplicates(keep="first", subset=indexes)
```

Has anyone any idea what could go wrong here?
Here is the full code if it helps: https://www.codepile.net/pile/BRx6W2e0

Comment: it looks like a bug in pandas. [Please report a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new)

Comment: If any of you experience the same problem as above, try switching from 32 bit Python to 64 bit Python. It solved my problem but not sure why because the memory consumpsion of my code was very low.